# Cannot create a JS popup via the Chrome Extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm trying to create my 1st Chrome extension, but I have issues to make my JS work properly.
All I want to do is, when I click on "Activer", it shows a popup that says "hello".

It's a code that i found in a github that i tried to adapt to my code.
When I inspect my extension, I'm getting an error that goes like this :

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
at HTMLDivElement.hello (chrome-extension://clolnlfhhjonbfknjgebnmnfanpmcono/popup.js:4:15)
```

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "e-kootsa",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Ce plugin vous permet d'écouter le texte d'une page",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Here is my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
.selection{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.global{
    padding-top: 5px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="global">
    <div class="selection"><a href="options.html" target="_blank">Paramètres</a></div>
    <hr />
    <div class="selection" id="clickme"><a href="#">Activer</a></div>
    <hr />
    <div class="selection"><a href="about.html" target="_blank">À propos</a>        </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the popup.js

```
// var app = chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage();

function hello() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
file: 'alert.js'
}); 
}

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', hello);
```

And here is my alert.js

```
alert('hello ' + document.location.href);
console.log('Tryhard');
```

I know I must have done some mistakes, but I still have difficulties to understand how to make things work...

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more conservative solution see [Xan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30166919/2545286)

======

It works with the active tab so you need to add permission in your manifest for every possible URL you want it to work = all URLs: `"permissions": ["<all_urls>"]`. So your manifest will look like this:

```
...
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
"options_page": "options.html"
```

Just adding that it should work fine.

Comment: See my answer for a more conservative solution, in case you did not know about this.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I did :)

Comment: Damn I love this community, it now works like a charm !

Answer (score 4):

[Samurai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30166648/934239) is valid, but falls short of optimal.

If you are working with the active tab like this, you don't need a blanket permission for everything. Declaring `<all_urls>` will result in scary warnings for the user on install.

There is a [special permission, `"activeTab"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab), specifically for this purpose. It grants permission for the current tab when the extension is invoked by the user (e.g. by pressing its button).

```
"permissions": ["activeTab"],
```